# Shopify DROPDOWN Variant

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, shopify-template, shopify-storefront-api

I'm currently customizing a Shopify store using the Dawn theme, and I'm facing a challenge with the product variant options. The theme comes with a default setup where both size and color options are presented as a dropdown and checkboxes, respectively.

However, I'd like to enhance the user experience by setting the size variant as a dropdown and representing the color options as visually appealing swatch buttons. I've explored the theme documentation, but I couldn't find a straightforward solution.

Here's a snippet of the existing code in my product-variant-options.liquid file:

```
{% if option.name == 'Color' %}
      {% assign variant_image_url = product.variants[forloop.index0].metafields.variant.image_url %}
      <label
        class="swColor"
        for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
        {% if variant_image_url %}
        style="background-image: url({{ variant_image_url }});"
        {% endif %}></label>
    {% else %}
      <label for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
        {{ value -}}
        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.variant_sold_out_or_unavailable' | t }}</span>
      </label>
    {% endif %}
```

How can I modify this code to set the size variant as a dropdown and the color options as visually appealing swatch buttons? Are there specific Liquid tags or JavaScript functions within the Dawn theme that I should leverage for this customization?

Any insights or code snippets would be immensely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with the HTML markup for select dropdowns?

Comment: Yes but one problem when i add if(option.name === 'Size') {
the dropdown loop 3 times horizontally but I want only one 
}

Comment: <select id="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}" name="dropdownOption">
  {% for value in option.values %}
    <option value="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information.